# Kartik-Widget GridView Filter TYPEAHEAD inactive

Tags: yii2

Following code throws out no error,but it's completely inactive, respectively redundant. JQuery is filtering nothing! Any ideas, how to fix this?
Here is code:

```html
        [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Land',
            'value' => function($model) {
                if ($model->name) {
                    return $model->name;
                } else {
                    return NULL;
                }
            },
            'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_TYPEAHEAD,
            'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'pluginOptions' => ['highlight' => true],
                //'dataset' => [['local' => array_values(\app\models\Country::find()->orderBy('name')->asArray()->one())]
                'dataset' => [['local' => array_values(ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Country::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'))]
                ]],
            'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'JQuery will filter...'],
            'format' => 'raw'
        ],
```

Here is var_dump of

```
 $ausgabe_ = array(array_values(ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Country::find()->all(), 'id', 'name')));
```

```html
E:\xampp\htdocs\Yii-WSL\views\country\index.php:145:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=25)
      0 => string 'Arabische Emirate' (length=17)
      1 => string 'Algerien' (length=8)
      2 => string 'Australia' (length=9)
      3 => string 'Belgien' (length=7)
      4 => string 'Brasilien' (length=9)
      5 => string 'Canada' (length=6)
      6 => string 'Schweiz' (length=7)
      7 => string 'China' (length=5)
      8 => string 'Zypern' (length=6)
      9 => string 'Germany' (length=7)
      10 => string 'Westsahara' (length=10)
      11 => string 'France' (length=6)
      12 => string 'United Kingdom' (length=14)
      13 => string 'Ungarn' (length=6)
      14 => string 'India' (length=5)
      15 => string 'Laos' (length=4)
      16 => string 'Russia' (length=6)
      17 => string 'Sudan' (length=5)
      18 => string 'Turkmenistan' (length=12)
      19 => string 'Ukraine' (length=7)
      20 => string 'Uganda' (length=6)
      21 => string 'United States' (length=13)
      22 => string 'Vatikanstadt' (length=12)
      23 => string 'Vietnam' (length=7)
      24 => string 'Südafrika' (length=10)
```

Any further ideas,how to fix this?
P.S.: If I try like this.....:

```
   'dataset' => [
   ['local' => array_values([ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Country::find()->orderBy('name')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name ')])],
   ]
```

....result of

```
 $ausgabe_ = array(array_values(ArrayHelper::map(Country::find()->orderBy('name')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name ')));
 var_dump($ausgabe_);
```

is like this:

```html
E:\xampp\htdocs\Yii-WSL\views\country\index.php:146:
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=25)
      0 => null
      1 => null
      2 => null
      3 => null
      4 => null
      5 => null
      6 => null
      7 => null
      8 => null
      9 => null
      10 => null
      11 => null
      12 => null
      13 => null
      14 => null
      15 => null
      16 => null
      17 => null
      18 => null
      19 => null
      20 => null
      21 => null
      22 => null
      23 => null
      24 => null
```

Nothing helps to fix this problem. Further ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worth to note the array must be with `integer` type indexes and there cannot be missing numbers (indexes) (for example, **0; 1; 2; 3** is fine but **0; 1; 3; 4** is not because index `2` is missing).

The only valid structure (as example):

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "Alpha"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "Beta"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "Gamma"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "Delta"
}
```

---

Your array is not valid:

1. The first (and only) element is 0 that contains other array. It cannot be like that;
2. That larger array has mixed indexes (read requirement in the first paragraph);
3. `null` values are not accepted.

What might solve your problem is if you use `array_values`:

```
'dataset' => [
    ['local' => array_values([ArrayHelper::map(\app\models\Country::find()->orderBy('name')->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name ')])],
],
```

Comment: I have no missing numbers. So, your guide didn't help,solving problem!

Comment: I need a little more info: 1. "inactive" means that you can type but nothing is shown upon entering first letter/number? 2. Can you write here what is the value (through `var_dump`) of `\app\models\Country::find()->orderBy('name')->asArray()->all()`?

Comment: 1. Exactly, so it is!  2. See upper supplements

Comment: I might be able to see what's wrong, but need one more thing. Can you also give the result with `ArrayHelper::map()`?

Comment: var_dump has been replaced, as u wanted!

Comment: Didnt help. See above.

Comment: Still invalid. You didn't properly copy my suggested code. You have 2nd level array while only the first level is acceptable (cannot be an array followed by another array).

Comment: If I try your sugesstion as it is, I just get null-values in var_dump()

Comment: Oh, I see I accidentally put an empty space in `ArrayHelper::map()` (after `name`). Remove that space and look again. I don't know what are the results overall. Does `name` column in DB exist?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I use SELECT2-Filter now, which works quite fine!